# Disable low battery notifications/warning on 15.04

Tags: power-management, laptop, battery, notification

I would like to disable the low battery warnings on Ubuntu 15.04 with Unity.  My laptop seems to have a faulty charge port or has trouble detecting the true charge of any battery I put in it, even brand new batteries, so I'm constantly being bombarded with low battery warnings.  I can't replace my laptop at the moment, either.

How can I disable the low battery warnings?

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me (on Ubuntu 16.04) was uninstalling the battery indicator:

```
sudo apt-get remove indicator-power
```

Followed by a reboot.

Answer (score 3):

Open dconf Editor and do the following.

Go to **org > unity > settings-daemon > plugins > power**

and unmark *notify-perhaps-recall*.

and change:

*Percentage-action*, *percentage-critical*, and *percentage-low*

to 0.

Revert these changes when you replace your battery.

Comment: When I go into dcomf I seem to be missing the option for Unity.  Gnome is there, though.

Comment: Do the same but with gnome,  try it may work. let me know what happens.